# Why crystal report Activex print dialog is not appeared in IE8+?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I have designed report using crystal report and I have set `PrintMode` attribute to `activex`.
but when I press the print button a popup is appeared but it is empty.
I have this problem just in IE8+.
What's wrong?

Comment: I am looking for the same solution. have u got the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the printControl.cab as an administrator on the client. You can find it [here](http://support.businessobjects.com/CRforVS2008/PrintControl.cab)

This is an activex control that allows you to print. For that reason I have chosen to use the pdf mode. If this doesn't work, try the compatibility mode button in IE.

Please update us with your results.